# Optional one to Optional one relationship in dotnet 3

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

user entity

```
public class User : IdentityUser<int>
{
    public UserAddress UserAddress { get; set; }
}
```

user address entity

```
public class UserAddress
{
    public int UserAddressId { get; set; }
    public string  City { get; set; }   
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public User User { get; set; }
}
```

want to add list of cities user can choose from it so i can add and delete and update it must be optional in userAddress and can add user without address and thanks